# Docker is failing to start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

for some reason, Docker is not starting on my VPS and I get the following when I do "systemctl status docker":

```
root@vps644072:~# service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-03-24 09:32:12 CET; 1min 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 21966 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 21966 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 24 09:32:12 vps644072 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 24 09:32:12 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 24 09:32:12 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 09:32:12 vps644072 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 24 09:32:28 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 24 09:32:28 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 09:32:28 vps644072 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 24 09:32:51 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 24 09:32:51 vps644072 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 09:32:51 vps644072 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by running "dpkg --configure -a". That seemed to also fix some other issues that I only just realised that I was having.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem in data storage, as @Shearman says reconfiguring it can be useful, but in case of a more serious error there is always the possibility of cleaning the directory `/var/lib/docker`